# Rails, Inputing test data into stripe-element in Capybara Systemtest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, capybara, minitest

I am trying to test the stripe part of a checkout process with a Capybara/Minitest Systemtest and do not know how to input the test card data into the stripe element.

This is one of the input fields:

```
<div class="CardNumberField-input-wrapper">
  <span class="InputContainer" data-max="4242 4242 4242 4242 4240">
    <input class="InputElement is-empty Input Input--empty" autocomplete="cc-number" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" type="tel" name="cardnumber" data-elements-stable-field-name="cardNumber" aria-label="Credit or debit card number" placeholder="Card number" aria-invalid="false" value=""></span></div>
  ..
```

The closest I got was with a simple:

```
fill_in('Card number', with: '4242424242424242')
```

which caused:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "Card number" that is not disabled
```

I suspect, that it might not be enough to target a field, but that you have to click the input field bevor.

When I try to target the CSS class:

```
find(class: 'CardNumberField-input-wrapper').fill_in('Card number', with: '4242424242424242')
```

I get:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css nil with classes [CardNumberField-input-wrapper]
```

How can I enable the disabled field? Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Van Holder's hint to work on the selector, I got it working with Xpath in the following way.

```
within_frame(find(:xpath, '//*[@id="card-element"]/div/iframe')) do
  find(:xpath, '//*[@id="root"]/form/div/div[2]/span[1]/span[2]/div/div[2]/span/input').fill_in with: '................'
  find(:xpath, '//*[@id="root"]/form/div/div[2]/span[2]/span/span/input').fill_in with: '....'
  find(:xpath, '//*[@id="root"]/form/div/div[2]/span[3]/span/span/input').fill_in with: '...'
  find(:xpath, '//*[@id="root"]/form/div/div[2]/span[4]/span/span/input').fill_in with: '.....'
end
```

Comment: +1 for this answer! Instead of wildcards in the xpath selectors, I had to use the full xpath for the inputs to get this to work :

`within_frame(find(:xpath, '//*[@id="card-element"]/div/iframe')) do
    find(:xpath, "/html/body/div/form/div/div[2]/span[1]/span[2]/div/div[2]/span/input").fill_in with: '4242424242424242'
    find(:xpath, "/html/body/div/form/div/div[2]/span[2]/span[1]/span/span/input").fill_in with: '12/27'
    find(:xpath, "/html/body/div/form/div/div[2]/span[2]/span[2]/span/span/input").fill_in with: '000'
end`

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the input element by name:

```rb
find('input["cardnumber"]')
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, In this case I get `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`.

Comment: The stripe-element is loaded in an iframe. Could it be that capybara/selenium does not find it therefore?

Comment: What about `page.find('input["cardnumber"]')`?

Comment: It is working with xpath!